# How to Split at Spaces and Other Non-Alphanumeric Character

Tags: c#, split

I'm setting up a new project in C# , and want to split string with this character but stay return empty space

```
 public static List<string> Tokinization(string stringy)
        {
            List<string> terms=new List<string>();
            char[] seps = new char[] { ' ',',','.','\n',};
            foreach (string ss in stringy.Split(seps))
            {
                terms.Add(ss);
            }
            return terms;
        }
```

The input is :

```
stringy="Mountain bike"
```

The actual result is :

```
terms{"","","",.........,"","Mountain","bike"}
```

However, I expect the  output of `terms{"Mountain","bike"}`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split at a whole newline sequence and not just `'\n'` you can use the overload taking a string array and options as argument.

```
public static List<string> Tokinization(string stringy)
{
    List<string> terms = new List<string>();
    foreach (string ss in stringy.Split(new string[] { " ", ",", ".", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    {
        terms.Add(ss);
    }
    return terms;
}
```

If you furthermore want to omit empty tokens in general you can also use the respective option.

```
public static List<string> Tokinization(string stringy)
{
    List<string> terms = new List<string>();
    foreach (string ss in stringy.Split(new string[] { " ", ",", ".", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        terms.Add(ss);
    }
    return terms;
}
```